# how to retrieve data from dynamically added label,drop down list in dynamically added div tag in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding label and drop down list(not a fixed number of label ,drop down list) dynamically to a form on ASP.NET page in C#, how do I read back data from these controls after post back the page?

Code:-

```
for (int newNames = 0; newNames < dtDDLBindName.Rows.Count; newNames++)
        {

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divMapClient = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            divMapClient.ID = 100 + "divMapClient" + newNames;
            divMapClient.Attributes.Add("class", "row");
            divMapClient.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");


            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divNewClients = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            divNewClients.ID = 100 + "divNewClients" + newNames;
            divNewClients.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            divNewClients.Attributes.Add("class", "col-sm-6");

            Label lblNewClientName = new Label();
            lblNewClientName.ID = "lblNewClientName" + newNames;
            lblNewClientName.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            lblNewClientName.Text = dtDDLBindName.Rows[newNames]["Investor Name"].ToString();


            divNewClients.Controls.Add(lblNewClientName);

            Label lblNewClientID = new Label();
            lblNewClientID.ID = "lblNewClientID" + newNames;
            lblNewClientID.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            lblNewClientID.Style.Add("display", "none");
            lblNewClientID.Text = dtDDLBindName.Rows[newNames]["Investor Id"].ToString();


            divNewClients.Controls.Add(lblNewClientID);

            divMapClient.Controls.Add(divNewClients);

            divmain.Controls.Add(divMapClient);

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl br = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("br");
            divmain.Controls.Add(br);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Control.FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes id of control as a string and find in this control.

```
Label l = (Label)ContainerControl.FindControl("ID");
```

You can assign ids to control in such a way that you can make ids of those controls. For example you create labels with ids lbl1, lbl2 then you can use a loop to get all labels.

```
for(int i=0 i < lablesCount; i++)
{
  Label l = (Label)ContainerControl.FindControl("lbl" + i);
  //Your processing goes here
}
```

Comment: my label is in div tag and this div also dyanamically added in another div tag

Comment: There would be some object in top hierarchy that is not dynamic or that is not the case you can use page object, this.FindControl

Comment: I already assign ID to all labels at  the time of generations. On button click event I want to access the data assign to label